# Rails: Catch REXML Request Parameter Parse Error in POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a REST API which accepts XML in HTTP Posts.

When I send wellformed XML, the XML is parsed and put in the params object.
For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
  <bar>Hello</bar>
</foo>
```

is available as: `"foo"=>{"bar"=>"Hello"}}`

But when I send malformed XML, Rails logs a REXML::ParseException and returns the HTML for this "Something went wrong"-site.

How can I catch this Exception so that I can respond with something more useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known problem. 
One solution could be http://github.com/kares/request_exception_handler